# Internal HDD not showing when boot Ubuntu from Flash drive for data recovery

Tags: boot, hard-drive, data-recovery

I am getting error 'operating System Not Found' when booting my Sony Vaio laptop with windows 7 OS. I checked the booting priority- first is internal HDD. In bios the HDD drive size show around 600 GB and so i think the HDD is not crashed. So I am trying to recover data from the HDD. I created one bootable flash drive of Ubuntu and booted. But the internal drive is not seeing in the left panel on desktop. please help me why it is so?

Below the lsblk result;

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 698.7G  0 disk 
sdb      8:16   1   3.6G  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   1   3.6G  0 part /cdrom
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  
loop0    7:0    0 975.9M  1 loop /rofs
```

Thanks

Comment: Run `lsblk` from a terminal on Ubuntu and add the output to your question please.

Comment: Hi Paul, Thanks for reply. Below is the output. ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 698.7G  0 disk 
sdb      8:16   1   3.6G  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   1   3.6G  0 part /cdrom
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  
loop0    7:0    0 975.9M  1 loop /rofs

Answer (score 1):

Install `ntfs-3g`

```
sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g ntfsprogs ntfstools
```

Type:

```
 su -i
 blkid
```

create a mountpoint

```
sudo mkdir /media/Data
```

Before editing /etc/fstab  make a backup

```
sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.orig
```

Type:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/fstab
```

add this line to the end of /etc/fstab:

```
UUID=EXAMPLE01422 /media/Data  ntfs-3g  defaults,windows_names,locale=en_US.utf8  0 0
```

Replace the UUID with the one relevant for your partition as shown in your blkid output.

You can fix windows partition through the following command:

```
sudo ntfsfix <partition>
```

`ntfsfix` is like `chkdsk` for windows machines

Update:
If you get an error after runing `sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g ntfsprogs ntfstools` edit `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Add the following lines:

```
   #ntfs-3g & fuse-2.5 repository: 
   deb http://flomertens.keo.in/ubuntu/ dapper main 
   deb-src http://flomertens.keo.in/ubuntu/ dapper main 

   #Givre's repository (ntfs-3g & fuse 2.5.3) 

   deb http://givre.cabspace.com/ubuntu/ dapper main
   deb-src http://givre.cabspace.com/ubuntu/ dapper main
```

save and update

Comment: When I run the first command I got error ' sudo aptitude command not found'. So I executed sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g .  Below the result; `ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
ntfs-3g is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo blkid`
But it stuck here... nothing hapens then...

Comment: i edit my answer , you are right . aptitude isn't installed you can use apt-get.

Comment: Ok. I executed the command. But got another error unable to locate.. below the result . NOte I an using bootable USB drive of Ubuntu and selected try option while booting(because I want to get the data from internal HDD)`ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g ntfsprogs ntfstools
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ntfsprogs
E: Unable to locate package ntfstools
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
`

Comment: @Tony i update my answer

Comment: I think you are saying to update with nano /etc/apt/sources.list I executed and added those lines. but.. how to save and update it? i am sorry I am new in Ubuntu :( I coud't see a menu to save/ update in files also

Comment: To save press ( ctrl +O) and hit Enter  to exit press ( ctrl +x)

Comment: to update type ; sudo apt-get update

Comment: when save. error permission denied

Comment: Run all command as root, type su then your root password

Comment: There is no root password so I just typed su only as blow(copied one line only). still permission eror. 
 su deb-src http://givre.cabspace.com/ubuntu/ dapper main

Comment: Open terminal and type ; su -i

Comment: now saved. but it stuck at sudo blkid nothing showing...

Comment: You need to run blkid as root, type su -i ,enter your root password  then type: blkid

Comment: i entered password. In root also the same problem. It shows nothing. Just blinking the cusror only