# Inserting a HDD from Windows 8.1 to Ubuntu 16.04 not accessing the Windows partition data

Tags: hard-drive, migration

I was using Windows 8.1 for Android Development from 2 HDDs, one for OS and other for SDK and code. But last week I migrated to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

I formatted the main HDD (having Windows) and installed Ubuntu in it. Now, after attaching the other drive, it is displayed in `Dashboard`, but not showing any data or partition in either `terminal` or in `Files`.

Since, I have no backup, I don't want to lose data. Is there any solution to get it back without inserting it to Windows and backing up data and re-insert to Ubuntu?

---

**What I tried**

- [Unable to mount Windows (NTFS) filesystem due to hibernation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation/145904#145904)
- [Unable to mount Windows 10 partition; it "is in an unsafe state"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state)
- [Internal HDD not showing when boot Ubuntu from Flash drive for data recovery](https://askubuntu.com/questions/739776/internal-hdd-not-showing-when-boot-ubuntu-from-flash-drive-for-data-recovery)
- [Hard drive not showing data after moving it to new computer, went from USB ext to internal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/742639/hard-drive-not-showing-data-after-moving-it-to-new-computer-went-from-usb-ext-t)
- [Failed to access Windows 8.1 NTFS partition from Ubuntu 13.10, even after disable fast startup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/457224/failed-to-access-windows-8-1-ntfs-partition-from-ubuntu-13-10-even-after-disabl/457401#457401)
- [How to make a partition windows can read?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145812/how-to-make-a-partition-windows-can-read)

But every effort was in vein.

---

Any help would be appriciated.

---

**EDIT**

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=7b1cdbf2-641e-4ac1-9ec2-7e58992047d4 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /home was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=df60b278-bf9b-4ae7-8140-93e2abb2b3dc /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=c17ef1f0-39b7-44fe-8e05-63673868deb9 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

---

```
$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sdb      8:16   0 149.1G  0 disk 
├─sdb2   8:18   0 148.9G  0 part /media/acme1/ACME
└─sdb1   8:17   0   200M  0 part 
sda      8:0    0 232.9G  0 disk 
├─sda2   8:2    0  57.2G  0 part /
├─sda5   8:5    0 171.9G  0 part /home
├─sda3   8:3    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda1   8:1    0   3.8G  0 part [SWAP]
```

---

```
$ df
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev             2512520       0   2512520   0% /dev
tmpfs             506744    7668    499076   2% /run
/dev/sda2       58927276 5919860  49991020  11% /
tmpfs            2533720   75668   2458052   3% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120       4      5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs            2533720       0   2533720   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda5      177238584 7771484 160440848   5% /home
tmpfs             506744      84    506660   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sdb2       61710332   89688  61620644   1% /media/acme1/ACME
```

---

```
$ ls /media/acme1/ACME
System Volume Information
```

Comment: May you share how do you mount and check data in this HDD?

Comment: Ya, sure. I plugged the HDD directly to the motherboard with SATA cable.

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: It shows you have only used 1% of this HDD. is it right?

Comment: No it has 2 partions. 1 is of around 55GB and other of 70GB and the later one has only 5GB around empty.

Comment: Also, in `properties` it shows 63GB or so Free Space, which it was before inserting it in Ubuntu. While other 85GB's details are not displayed, since HDD's capacity is 160GB.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56531/discussion-between-salim-shivani-and-mostafa-ahangarha).

Comment: Please check your HDD on a windows machine and make sure it is working properly there. It appears to me that there is something wrong with it.

Comment: Okay let me try. And thank you very much for your time

Comment: Yes in Windows machine, the data is as it is and works properly.

Comment: please run this also: `mount | grep sdb` to see how the HDD is mounted

Comment: it give the following message: `/dev/sdb2 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
/dev/sdb5 on /home type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)`

Comment: The problem is found. your device is mounted wrongly as ext4 filesystem. I come with an answer. and please move the last comment into your question (as I asked before) and remove all the unnecessary comments. It would be great if you provide the result of `cat /etc/fstab`

Comment: If Windows 8 or later you have fast start up or hibernation. And that keeps everything mounted. You need to turn off the fast startup in Windows to make sure all NTFS partitions are unmounted. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions More explanation of NTFS driver & Windows hibernation
http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to mount Windows (NTFS) filesystem due to hibernation](http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation)

Comment: I tried all that solutions but none of them worked. Also, restarted the system but, it also didn't worked. Hence, it is not duplicate the given link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for your response and time.

Finally, I solved the issue by formatting the HDD with `FAT32` partition type and `windows` for the use.

I thought to format that HDD with partition type `FAT32` after getting the data in other disk. I was experimenting it since after the efforts of more than a week, I was not succeeded.

**This thought came after I read somewhere regarding this in some link given in the above links.**

This led me to succeed and maybe it can help someone else too facing the same situation.

I am now able to use that particular partition in `Ubuntu` as well as `Windows`.

Once again, Thank You very much for the guidance and help.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely the system did not install the tools needed to use NTFS formatted disks since you had no Windows disk connected to it. It would have installed those tools if you had the disk connected to the system when you installed Ubuntu.

You can install NTFS support with

```
sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g
```

After that reconnect the drive and see if it shows content.

Comment: will it leave the data as it is?

Comment: That command? Yes. It installs software on your Ubuntu that tells Ubuntu how to handle windows filesystems.

Comment: okay, let me try

Comment: it shows the following result.
`Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
ntfs-3g is already the newest version (1:2015.3.14AR.1-1ubuntu0.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 113 not upgraded.`

Comment: i restarted after that command, but in vain. it doesnt show any data. just detects the HDD only.

Comment: when you try to mount the partition in nautilus, does it gets successfully mounted or it shows error?

Comment: `sudo ntfsfix -b -d /dev/sda1` regardless of that try this command (note sda1 should be replaced by the partition number which isn't working. this might help but it'll surely do no harm

Comment: @Rinzwind are you still available?

Comment: @SumeetDeshmukh i have not installed `nautilus`.

Comment: @SumeetDeshmukh `sudo ntfs -b -d /dev/sda1` gives an error `Mounting volume... NTFS signature is missing.
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors... NTFS signature is missing.
FAILED
Failed to startup volume: Invalid argument
NTFS signature is missing.
Trying the alternate boot sector
Unrecoverable error
Volume is corrupt. You should run chkdsk.`

Comment: i replaced sda with HDD's volume number

Comment: You need windows to repair the disk. It was in an unsafe state when you last disconnected it. Maybe with the Linux tool ntfsfix it should be part of those NTFS tools

Answer (score 0):

Based on the result of running the `mount` command, your HDD is mounted as ext4 which is wrong.

- Unmount your device
- Make a mount point (in not already existed) by making a folder in /media/:

  ```
  sudo mkdir /media/acme1/ACME
  ```
- Mount it manually by running:

  ```
  sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sdb2 /media/acme1/ACME
  ```

Now, you should see all your files.

I assume there is a line in your `/etc/fstab` which is making this drive be automatically mounted as ext4. If you share the content of this file, the problem can be solved permanently.

Comment: Any success? Please update

Comment: I just came to ofc and inserted HDD back to Ubuntu. I am checking it.

Comment: i updated my question, with the output of the above command.

Comment: DO NOT REMOVE RESULT OF OTHER COMMANDS YOU RAN. THEY ARE NEEDED. `/etc/fstab` is fine. Did you do what I said in the answer? result?

Comment: Ya i tried that too. It shows the following error: `NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sdb' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?`

Comment: I wish you would ckeck the filesytem of your HDD. if it is not NTFS, then it should be fat. replace ntfs with vfat and try again

Comment: when i checked in Windows system, it was NTFS

Comment: Then use `ntfs-3g`

Comment: It shows following message: `$ sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sdb2 /media/acme1/ACME
[sudo] password for acme1: 
The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb2': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.`

Comment: Oh! Now it is clear why you cannot mount it. to read this Harddisk, you either should mount it in Readonly mode or you should deactivate hibernation in Windows. Your solution is here: http://askubuntu.com/a/145904/214264

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56644/discussion-between-salim-shivani-and-mostafa-ahangarha).